# How to check whether user has access to embedded google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, iframe, google-sheets-api

My website contains embedded Google sheets with access restricted to Google accounts from my organization. The website itself doesn't require user authentication. When the user accesses the embedded Google sheet without being logged into the correct Google account from my organization, they see a "403. That's an error. We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page." error message in the iframe.

I would like to be able to detect when the user is seeing this error, so I can add my own UI element to prompt them to log into the correct google account to access the sheet in the iframe. This seems tricky due to cross-domain security measures. I can't directly check the content of the iframe for the error text. Is there some API or other method I can use to check whether the user is logged into a certain google account?

Alternatively, is there a way I can customize the 403 error message with my own text?